# Problem with sudo apt update in Ubuntu 18.04: Post-Invoke-Success if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04

The terminal gave me these errors when updating the software with `sudo apt update`.

```
Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                     
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Traceback (most recent call last):                    
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
Reading packages list... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success   
 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db;     
 then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'  
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

These are the results of `sudo apt install --reinstall command-not-found`

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5.188 B of archives
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading the database ... 225797 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparations for extracting ... / command-not-found_18.04.4_all.deb ...
Extracting command-not-found (18.04.4) on (18.04.4) ...
Configuring command-not-found (18.04.4) ...
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
```

When I tried the command `sudo apt update` again after reinstalling command-not-found, the results were the same as described in the first text block.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found/+bug/1876034/comments/2

Answer (score 13):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
apt download python3-minimal
sudo apt install --reinstall ./python3-minimal_*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

If that doesn't work a simple reboot will sometimes solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my same/similar issue:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
ls -la /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Source: [Linux Question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/errors-trying-to-run-apt-get-update-4175665017/)

Answer (score 1):

> Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...

was plaguing my system too ... and for a newbie fuller explanation of the above method - THAT WORKED - WOOHOO! ... here is what I did!

Codes are used inside of terminal of course ...

```
sudo find / -name 'CommandNotFound'
```

resulted in this, showing this obscure path

> [sudo] password for ack: 
>   find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound

So the unobvious part of the above method quoted here ...

```
sudo cp -r /path/of/CommandNotFound /usr/lib/
```

resulted in an error, obviously as it is "Generic" so to speak

but this altered version with this file path found in the first command solved the problem ... "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound"

```
$ sudo cp -r /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound /usr/lib/
```

and the problem is gone

I hope this helps, Mark

Answer (score 1):

`apt` is using several third party tools, among them `command-not-found`. This is meant to react to unknown commands and suggest which packages you'd need to install to get those commands. But the `command-not-found` package had not been maintained for several years, which led to multiple problems.

To sort out [one specific problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308270/acquiregzipindexes-causes-apt-to-fail/1308537?noredirect=1#comment2410263_1308537), in late 2021 some helpful people [built new versions of the `command-not-found` package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found/+bug/1876034) for several Ubuntu versions. So, if you're using either Focal / 20.04, Hirsute / 21.04, or Impish / 21.10, you want to make sure that you have the latest version of `command-not-found` for your respective distribution.

For other distributions, you may consider disabling `Acquire::GzipIndexes` in `apt`'s configuration (because those compressed indexes tripped `command-not-found` up this time around). Or you may consider uninstalling the `command-not-found` package, if you don't need it for other purposes. But I haven't looked into any possible side effects of removing the package.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem, and fixed it by this way:

```
sudo find / -name 'CommandNotFound'
sudo cp -r /path/of/CommandNotFound /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but this is my current workaround:

```
sudo apt purge command-not-found 
sudo apt --purge autoremove
sudo bash -c 'apt update && apt full-upgrade && apt autoremove && apt clean'
```