# System upgrade from 20.04. to 22.04. Problem executing scripts

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, error-handling

E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi', E:Sub-process returned an error code

Comment: We need more information around that, is there other data before that or such for error messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with sudo apt update in Ubuntu 18.04: Post-Invoke-Success if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041226/problem-with-sudo-apt-update-in-ubuntu-18-04-post-invoke-success-if-usr-bin-te)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working!

Comment: We need more information around that, is there other data before that or such for error messages... I start the normal upgrade process only